# Контроллер в подпапке

Tags: php, yii2

Имеется модуль, внутри которого находится каталог `controllers`. Внутри находится файл контроллера `defaultController`.

Как получить возможность использовать контроллер в таком виде: `module/controllers/MYNAME/newController.php`

Answer (score 1):

Создайте модуль в модуле. Структура будет примерно такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также можно попробовать поиграться с правилами роутинга, чтобы получить более красивый url-адрес:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'showScriptName' => false,   // Disable index.php
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,   // Disable r= routes
    'rules' => [
        '<module:(first-level)>/<secondModule:(second-level)>/<action:[\w-]+>' => '<module>/<secondModule>/new-controller/<action>',
    ]
],
```

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы этот внутренний модуль загружался по адресу:
my.local/first-level/second-level/new ?

Comment: Но чтобы он не открывался по прямому пути типа my.local/second-level

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Используйте настройки urlManager.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я тут еще вопросик написал, может поможете?
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467687/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-rbac