# Узнать конкретную роль пользователя RBAC

Tags: yii2

Как я могу узнать конкретную роль пользователя RBAC если ролей у юзера несколько.
Желательно одним запросом.

Comment: или же лучше в саму таблицу юзера занести столб "основная роль"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В системе RBAC нет такого понятия как "основная роль". Её можно искусственно получить только если у пользователя будет всегда только одна роль, которая будет подключать необходимые ей пермишены. Такой подход очень сильно ограничивает возможности RBAC.

Такая ситуация может возникнуть когда появляется желание дать менеджерам возможность простым селектбоксом переключать роли пользователей. Как альтернативу вы можете ввести чекбоксы, это позволит сохранить всю мощь RBAC.

Попробуйте использовать [этот компонент](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin) для управления доступами, а также [ознакомиться с документацией](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) для того чтобы выбрать наилучший способ решения вашей задачи.

Comment: Да, я его и использую.
Дело в том что у меня есть главный контроллер main. При вызове которого происходит пере направление на другой подконтроллер в зависимости от основной роли юзера.
Незнаю как поступить тут..

Comment: Определяйте что пользователю нужно перенаправление, например, назначьте ему пермишен и проверяйте его наличие.

Comment: Извини пожалуйста, ты не мог бы мне лично помочь сообразить. Возможно по скайпу, передо мной стоит задача, вроде не сложная, но в то же время я не понимаю как её решить, я думаю для тебя это пустяк. Оч прошу, бьюсь уже около месяца

Comment: @Mr.Music го в чат https://gitter.im/onedevlink